# Odoo 16 community. Error when sending quotations. RPC_ERROR

Tags: odoo

I don´t understand why sending quotations is not working.

At the beginning of the error message I get this:

```
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env
```

Here the error message:

```
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1613, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1810, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 149, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 699, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/dynamic_odoo/models/models.py", line 36, in onchange
    result = _onchange(self, values, field_name, field_onchange)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 6489, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 6200, in _onchange_eval
    method_res = method(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 177, in _onchange_template_id_wrapper
    values = self._onchange_template_id(self.template_id.id, self.composition_mode, self.model, self.res_id)['value']
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 575, in _onchange_template_id
    values = self.generate_email_for_composer(
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 705, in generate_email_for_composer
    template_values = self.env['mail.template'].with_context(tpl_partners_only=True).browse(template_id).generate_email(res_ids, fields)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account_edi/models/mail_template.py", line 35, in generate_email
    res = super().generate_email(res_ids, fields)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 286, in generate_email
    result, report_format = self.env['ir.actions.report']._render_qweb_pdf(report, [res_id])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 54, in _render_qweb_pdf
    return super()._render_qweb_pdf(report_ref, res_ids=res_ids, data=data)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 793, in _render_qweb_pdf
    collected_streams = self._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account_edi_ubl_cii/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 58, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    collected_streams = super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account_edi/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 14, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    collected_streams = super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 17, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    return super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 694, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    html = self.with_context(**additional_context)._render_qweb_html(report_ref, res_ids_wo_stream, data=data)[0]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/dynamic_odoo/models/ir_actions.py", line 46, in _render_qweb_html
    return super(IrActionsReport, self.with_context(REPORT_ID=self.search([('report_name', '=', report_ref)]).id))._render_qweb_html(report_ref, docids, data=data)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 1508, in search
    res = self._search(domain, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4618, in _search
    query = self._where_calc(domain)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4386, in _where_calc
    return expression.expression(domain, self).query
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 447, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 1024, in parse
    expr, params = self.__leaf_to_sql(leaf, model, alias)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 1044, in __leaf_to_sql
    assert not isinstance(right, BaseModel), \
AssertionError: Invalid value ir.actions.report(352,) in domain term ('report_name', '=', ir.actions.report(352,))
```

The same is happening when sending invoices etc. Otherwise our Odoo is working fine. The odoo system email is working too. Server: Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: From where do you want to send quotations? Using the web API or somewhere from business logic?

Comment: line 46 is now:  return super(IrActionsReport, self.with_context(REPORT_ID=self.search([('report_name', '=', report.name)]).id))._render_qweb_html(report_ref, docids, data=data)

Comment: Shows error: return super(IrActionsReport, self.with_context(REPORT_ID=self.search([('report_name', '=', report.name)]).id))._render_qweb_html(report_ref, docids, data=data)
NameError: name 'report' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The `dynamic_odoo` module overrides the `_render_qweb_html` to update the context and use an instance of `ir.actions.report` as a value in the search function domain which, this is not supported and Odoo will raise an error.

You used the report name field on the left side so you need need to use the `report_ref.report_name` field value.

Because the function could be called using a `report_name` (Report template) or an ID (integer), the function will raise an error. The solution is to get the report ID depending on the `report_ref` value (record, ID, or External ID), Odoo already has a function to do that and it is called `_get_report`.

Use [_get_report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L501) function to get the report record then update the context

***Example:***

```py
@api.model
def _render_qweb_html(self, report_ref, docids, data=None):
    report = self._get_report(report_ref)
    return super(IrActionsReport, self.with_context(REPORT_ID=report.id))._render_qweb_html(report_ref, docids, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed myself that an error message appears when Odoo Community Studio is installed. When I uninstall Community Studio, emails are sent normally. Have others had similar experiences?